# Force user to allow facebook permissions using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I developed Facebook application and I have some problems on "Allow access step",In initial stage user must authorize app and permissions.Currently if users skip extended permissions also landing to application home page , But I need to force user to accept all permissions, I got success when using FQL method , Now its not working , I cant find out the solution. Here is my code

```
$TotalPermissions = UserAndFriendsPermissions();
return true;
$tp = substr_replace($TotalPermissions ,"",-1);
$this->loadClassFile("Facebook", MAIN_PLUGIN_PATH."Common/facebook/facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => $FBConnect["fb_app_id"],'secret' => $FBConnect["fb_secret_key"],));
$params = array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => "SELECT ".$tp." FROM permissions WHERE uid=me()");

$result = $facebook->api($params);
$totalp = count(explode(",",$tp));
$ap=0;
foreach ($result[0] as $key => $val) 
{
if($val==1)
 {
   $ap++;
                        }
                    } 
                    if($ap==$totalp)
                    {
                    return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    Redirect("https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force users to accept all your extended permissions. What you can do is to check for permissions given and handle those cases accordingly i.e. redirecting users who have not given permission to a landing page which explains why you need those permissions.